# how to get time stamp with date in datetimepicker using jQuery for SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I've a dateandtime field which displays only date, how can I include time as well?

Here is the function am using:
$('#ArrTime').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment(),
        format: 'hh:mm:ss',
        ignoreReadonly: true
    });

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I resolved this, by changing the function to:
$('#ArrTime').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  minDate: moment(),
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm',
  ignoreReadonly: true
 });
But, the time is not being saved into a SharePoint list while Date is getting saved, any  help?

Comment: Any help here, on why the time stamp is not getting saved in the SharePoint list:
$("#ArrTime input[type='text']").val(Onsite_Arrival_Time_for_Meeting.getMonth()+1 +"/" +Onsite_Arrival_Time_for_Meeting.getDate()+"/"+Onsite_Arrival_Time_for_Meeting.getFullYear() +" "+Onsite_Arrival_Time_for_Meeting.getHours() +":" +
    Onsite_Arrival_Time_for_Meeting.getMinutes());

Is there any error in this?